# How to get the cd shell-builtin to stop guessing?

Tags: bash, directory, cd-command, shell-builtin, pwd

For example:

```
$ ls -aF
./ ../ bin/
$ cd tin # with a tee, not bee
bin
$ pwd
/home/user/bin
```

In other words, `cd` guesses that what I really meant was `cd bin`, and *successfully* (huh?) changes the current directory accordingly. I do not find this behavior documented in `man bash` or the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).

I would like Bash to produce an error, write something informative to standard error, *and leave the current directory unchanged* if no directory matching the `dir` argument (accounting for [expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)) is found.

FYI,

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ ps -p $$
PID TTY          TIME CMD
46959 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname:
         Icon name: computer-server
           Chassis: server
        Machine ID:
           Boot ID: 
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.83.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
$ #DELETED: Static hostname, Machine ID, Boot ID
```

Answer (score 45):

The behavior of the `cd` command is affected by `shopt`. See `man bash`, search: `shopt`. See also the [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

In particular, the behavior illustrated in the question is consistent with `shopt -s cdspell`.

I suppose clearing all options affecting `cd` would have the desired (per the question) effect. See the description of `cd` among the [Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) or under "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" in `man bash`.

### Acknowledgement

Credit to an unnamed coworker for pointing out our system's `shopt` setting of `cdspell`, also acknowledged in an earlier comment.

Comment: Also look up `CDPATH` in the shell man page.

Comment: Shells like tcsh or zsh will have better ways to offer spelling corrections, either with dedicated configurable prompts when you enter commands or via the completion system.

Comment: ObJargonFile: [DWIM](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html).